# Pulseaudio: 'Daemon already running' and 'pa_pid_file_create() failed'

Tags: arch-linux, pulseaudio

Because my laptop has no audio I recently installed pulseaudio and I was following the [First Steps](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/FirstSteps/) page. First I tried the command `pulseaudio -nC` but nothing happends. Then reading the documentation I enterd `pulseaudio --start` and `pulseaudio -nC` wich returned the following output:

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

Before all of that I just installed it with pacman: `pacman -S pulseaudio`

Answer (score 3):

Pulseaudio appears to be already running. To stop: `systemctl --user stop pulseaudio` and to launch `systemctl --user start pulseaudio`. Also, to view its output do `journalctl pulseaudio`. Check out the wiki for more: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio

I strongly recommend using PipeWire instead though, it works much better. Here's how to pipewire in Arch: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire.

tl;dr `sudo pacman -S wireplumber pipewire-pulse pipewire-alsa pipewire-x11-bell pipewire-zeroconf`, yes, replace pulseaudio, then `systemctl --user enable --now pipewire-pulse.service pipewire.service`