# Missing audio from system settings

Tags: fedora, audio, kde, pulseaudio

I was trying to diagnose why my headphones weren't working while speakers were, and decided to reinstall `pulseaudio` and `pipewire`. In the process, It looks like I deleted something else that I shouldn't have but don't know what. When I restarted the system my audio controls were gone. I still have audio and can control it using pavucontrol but I can't use hardware buttons for control anymore.

Pulseaudio gives me the exact error from this question: [Pulseaudio: 'Daemon already running' and 'pa_pid_file_create() failed'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/628544/pulseaudio-daemon-already-running-and-pa-pid-file-create-failed)

That didn't help.

I'm running fedora 37, KDE plasma 5.27.3 . My hardware is asus strix 17 gl703ge. 00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)

I'm relatively new to linux so if you need any more information juts tell me.